# Listener Output according to Priority

Tags: c#, .net, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5

I am currently using the Logging framework in Enterprise Library. Does anyone know how to use Priority to control the output for each Listener? For example, this listener only output the information to the target if the Priority of the log is higher than 3. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I know predefined listener doesn't support filter by priority. Simple solution is to use severity. 
I think you can use CustomTraceListener to filter by whatever you want.